# Processing an XSLT input file to remove particular content from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have requirement to handle an XSLT code, where incase if an XSL tag element has an attribute value of enable="yes", then the corresponding tag has to be removed from the output.

Where my input xsl file is as below,

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="/">   
    <xsl:for-each select="Node/Node_1">
    <node>
    <line enable="false"><xsl:value-of select="Line"/></line>
    <text><xsl:value-of select="Text"/></text>
    <desc enable="false"><xsl:value-of select="Desc"/></desc>
    <cust><xsl:value-of select="Cust"/></cust>
    </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the output data has to remove the corresponding XSL tag which has the attribute enable="false",

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


    <xsl:template match="/">   
    <xsl:for-each select="Node/Node_1">
    <node>
    <text><xsl:value-of select="Text"/></text>
    <cust><xsl:value-of select="Cust"/></cust>
    </node>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>    
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is it feasible through XSLT itself, by treated an xsl file as an XML and processing it to remove the tags which has the attribute of enable="false".. Or is there any better way to accomplish it ?

Comment: Yes you can do it, but have you considered using the XSLT 2.0 standard attribute `use-when="false()"` instead? Then you wouldn't need to do the preprocessing, the XSLT processor would do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to write one another xslt where you have to use:

- identity template
- Template for

Or make xsl as XML then use this XSLT you will get ouptpu:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@enable = 'yes']"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[@enable = 'false']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to do this, an empty template `<xsl:template match="*[@enable = 'false']"/>` together with the identity transformation achieves this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="*[@enable = 'false']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMh is an XSLT 3 sample, in earlier versions of XSLT  you need to replace the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` by the spelled out identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately XSLT 3 is not supported for me.. Am using XSLT 1.0, I used the one which is posted in the first comment and that worked for me as expected.. Thank you so much.